# How to change tab content in android Tabhost?

Tags: android, android-tabhost

I am having 3 Tabs Tab1,tab2, Tab3. In tab1 I am loading page1.java. In page1 there is a Next button. I need to change to page2.java while tap on the next button on Page1.java. I need to change only the content. I need the tabs there as permanent. Is it possible. 
I am doing like this on next button click,

```
Intent nextPageIntent = new Intent(context, Page2.class);
startActivity(nextPageIntent);
```

Please help me.

Comment: needs more relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

For that reason you need a `ActivityGroup` within the Tab where you want to change the Activity.

```
    TabHost tabHost = getTabHost();

    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab1").setIndicator("Page1").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Page1.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab2").setIndicator("Page2").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Page2.class)));
    tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Page3").setContent(
            new Intent(this, Page3.class)));
```

The `Page1` takes care which Activity is shown in the first tab. With `setContentView` you can bring another View to the front after an action is triggered.

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, Page2.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

    View view = Page1.group.getLocalActivityManager().
                startActivity(intent).getPage2View();

    Page1.group.setContentView(view);
```

You need to tell the ActivityGroup which view is to be on top and set the appropriate Flag, so that the View will be on top.

Of course now you have to keep track which activity is in front, how they behave and what happens if the back button is pressed. But that gives you room for customizing the behavior.

More from: [use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity](http://united-coders.com/nico-heid/use-android-activitygroup-within-tabhost-to-show-different-activity/).

Comment: I am doing like this. But The tab will go. Its loading as new page.

Comment: @SHIDHI - You then need to set the tab with the method `setCurrenttab`. See update.

Comment: I am not talking about changing tab. I want to change the content of tab1. Now it is Page1  and in next button press i need to to change it to page2 from page1 .

Answer (score 0):

`tabHost.setCurrentTab(2)` should do it.

Comment: I am not talking about changing tab. I want to change the content of tab1. Now it is Page1 and in next button press i need to to change it to page2 from page1 .

Answer (score 0):

You can try [replacing fragment](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/04/replace-fragment.html) for that.

So keep all your pages (for one tab) in separate fragment. Load fragment 1 - i.e. Page 1 initially, and on click of Next Button, replace fragment like this:

```
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {

        Page2Fragment fragment = (Page2Fragment)myFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(TAG_1);

        if (fragment == null) {

            //load page 2 in fragment
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = myFragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.maincontainer, myFragment1, TAG_1);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.